# Parsing XML XmlPullParser android

Tags: android, xmlpullparser

i'm using xmlpullparser in android to parse an xml document that looks like :

```
<top>
  <category>
    <name></name>
    <desc></desc>
    <songs>
      <song>
        <clip></clip>
        <thumb></thumb>
      </song>
      <song>
        <clip></clip>
        <thumb></thumb>
      </song>
    </songs>
  </category>
</top>
```

I tried this :

```
while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT && !done){
                String name = null;
                switch (eventType){
                    case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
                        categoriesSong = new ArrayList<TopMousika>();
                        break;
                    case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                        name = parser.getName();
                        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(CATEGORY)){
                            currentCategory = new TopMousika();
                            currentCategory.setId(parser.getAttributeValue(0));
                            currentCategory.setId(parser.getAttributeValue(1));
                        } else if (currentCategory != null){
                            if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(NAME)){
                                currentCategory.setName(parser.nextText());
                            } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(DESCRIPTION)){
                                currentCategory.setDescription(parser.nextText());
                            } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(THUMBNAIL)){
                                currentCategory.setThumbnail(parser.nextText());
                            } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(SONGS)){
                                songs = new ArrayList<SongMousika>();
                                if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(SONG)){
                                    currentSong = new SongMousika();
                                    currentSong.setId(parser.getAttributeValue(0));
                                    Log.d("TEST", "OK");
                                    songs.add(currentSong);
                                } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(TITLE)){
                                    Log.d("TEST", "OK2");
                                    currentSong.setTitle(parser.nextText());
                                } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(SINGER)){
                                    currentSong.setTitle(parser.nextText());
                                } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(THUMBNAIL)){
                                    currentSong.setTitle(parser.nextText());
                                } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(PUBLICATION_DATE)){
                                    currentSong.setTitle(parser.nextText());
                                } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(CLIP)){
                                    currentSong.setTitle(parser.nextText());
                                }
                                currentCategory.setSongs(songs);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                        name = parser.getName();
                        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(CATEGORY) && 
currentCategory != null){
                            currentCategory.setSongs(songs);
                            categoriesSong.add(currentCategory);
                        } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(TOP)){
                            done = true;
                        }
                        break;
                }
                eventType = parser.next();
            }
```

but I can not retrieve my Songs List.

can any one help me please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be expecting `name` to change magically between checks:

```
if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(SONGS)) {
    songs = new ArrayList<SongMousika>();
    if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(SONG)) {
```

How is it going to be `SONG` *and* `SONGS`? You need to keep pulling XML and react to each element name differently *in the loop*. So you'll probably have a bunch of `if/else if` statements without any nesting when reacting to a START_TAG event. (It's very likely to be worth pulling the handling of that into a separate method, by the way.)

EDIT: Okay, so you need to make each iteration of the loop just react to *one tag*. So your handling for a start tag would be something like:

```
case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
    name = parser.getName();
    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(CATEGORY)){
        currentCategory = new TopMousika();
        currentCategory.setId(parser.getAttributeValue(0));
        currentCategory.setId(parser.getAttributeValue(1));
    } else if (currentCategory != null) {
        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(NAME)){
            currentCategory.setName(parser.nextText());
        } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(DESCRIPTION)){
            currentCategory.setDescription(parser.nextText());
        } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(THUMBNAIL)){
            currentCategory.setThumbnail(parser.nextText());
        } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(SONGS)){
            songs = new ArrayList<SongMousika>();
        } else if (songs != null) {
            if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(SONG)) {
                currentSong = new SongMousika();
                currentSong.setId(parser.getAttributeValue(0));
                Log.d("TEST", "OK");
                songs.add(currentSong);
            } else if (currentSong != null) {
                 else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(TITLE)) {
                    Log.d("TEST", "OK2");
                    currentSong.setTitle(parser.nextText());
                } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(SINGER)){
                    currentSong.setSinger(parser.nextText());
                } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(THUMBNAIL))
                    // etc
                }
            }
        }
```

Note how in any path through there we never check for `name` having multiple values - we say:

- Are we starting a new category?

  - If so, create it and remember it - then continue with the next iteration.
  - If not (and if we've *got* a category), are we starting a new song list?
  - If so, create it and remember it - then continue with the next iteration.
  - If not (and if we've *got* a song list), are we starting a new song?

    - If so, create it and remember it - then continue with the next iteration.
    - If not (and if we've *got* a song)...
    - Are we reading the title? If so, read the text and set it, then continue.
    - Are we reading the singer? If so, read the text and set it, then continue.
    - Are we reading the thumbnail? If so, read the text and set it, then continue.
    - etc

Comment: thanks for your answer, i've followed the example in IBM DeveloperWorks [link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/)

Comment: @wael: No you haven't. Try to find an example in there where they check whether `name` equals one value and then *within that condition* check whether `name` equals another value. They check for `currentMessage` being null and check for various names within that, but that's not the same thing. Do you understand now why it's not working?

Comment: would you please explain more about **You need to keep pulling XML and react to each element name differently in the loop**